# Not able to score test data after loading the h2o random forest model object again

Tags: r, random-forest, h2o

I am using `h2o` package in `R` to build random forest models. My task requires me to score test data repeatedly at later times, so I save the random forest model object as follows.

```
save("D:/model_random_forest.RData")
```

To score the data, I load back the model object again in the memory later as follows

```
 load("D:/model_random_forest.RData")
```

But when I score using

```
scores <- h2o.predict(model_random_forest, test_data)
```

I get the following error

```
    ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 404 Not Found (url =     http://127.0.0.1:54321/3/Predictions/models/DRF_model_R_1442519642868_26/frames/test17_normal.hex_2)

water.exceptions.H2OKeyNotFoundArgumentException
 [1] "water.api.ModelMetricsHandler.predict(ModelMetricsHandler.java:203)"   
 [2] "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"           
 [3] "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)"           
 [4] "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)"       
 [5] "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)"                       
 [6] "water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:58)"                             
 [7] "water.api.RequestServer.handle(RequestServer.java:637)"                
 [8] "water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:578)"                 
 [9] "water.JettyHTTPD$H2oDefaultServlet.doGeneric(JettyHTTPD.java:617)"     
 [10] "water.JettyHTTPD$H2oDefaultServlet.doPost(JettyHTTPD.java:565)"          
 [11] "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)"          
 [12] "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)"          
 [13]     "org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)"

Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(conn = conn, h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion,    : 
  Object 'DRF_model_R_1442519642868_26' not found in function: predict for  argument: model
```

The whole saving, loading and scoring approach works fine when I use R packages to build models, but somehow failing here. Can someone please provide a solution to it? I can not keep rebuilding the model again again every I want to score some data.

H2o connection seems to be fine since when the model is newly built and is still present in the memory, scoring happens smoothly.

Answer (score 3):

H2O model objects are different from R-objects. H2O model object is stored in H2O cluster and in R you can see only reference to it which looks like a normal R model. Hence, if you save your R session, and restart it later, probably you will be running against different H2O cluster which does not have the model referenced by your R-session.

The solution is to save/load H2O model via `h2o.saveModel`/`h2o.saveModel` methods.

For example:

```
model <- h2o.randomForest(...)
model_path <- h2o.saveModel(
        object = model, 
        path = "/tmp/mymodel", 
        force = TRUE)

print(model_path)
```

See documentation for more examples: http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-slater/5/docs-website/h2o-r/h2o_package.pdf